# Converting String to List by slicing: Possibly a Control Flow/ Syntax query

Tags: python, syntax

I found code that already converts a string to list, but I am trying to understand the part  `list1[:0]=string`. Could you kindly explain to me how this would work? I understand the `[:0]` part.

What I am trying to understand is why the line is written the way it is written, because reading it from left to right doesn't make sense to me. I reckoned that the leftmost part would generally be a variable to which things would be assigned, which would happen using the = sign. Any explanation would be appreciated, and apologies for the Noob question.

```
# Python code to convert string to list character-wise
def Convert(string):
    list1=[]
    list1[:0]=string
    return list1

str1="ABCD"
print(Convert(str1))
```

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just use `list(string)`?

Comment: God. I completely blanked on that. It makes lif simple. Thanks!
But, the question still holds. I mostly ask because I am sure I am missing something in why that function works.

Comment: The infinite bounty of google, and 5 days into learning Python. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `list1[:0]` is just a zero-length slice. Python will adjust the size of the list in slice assignments to accommodate ([documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)). It's instructive to look at : `list1=[1, 2, 3, 4]; list1[1:2] = 'hello'`

Comment: :) Thanks! this makes sense. 
Also thanks for the link to the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, but it is a variable! We're just adding slice magic to our `list` (or more specifically, our [`sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-sequence)).

It's a bit easier to see what's going on if we extend the example a bit:

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list[:0] = "1234"
>>> my_list
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> my_list[:0] = "5678"
>>> my_list
['5', '6', '7', '8', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

The assignment operation is assigning the contents of the `sequence` (our string) to the positions in the list up to index `0` (which does not include index `0`). Python helpfully automatically makes room at the front of the list, and then inserts the elements of the `sequence` (which in this case is a `sequence` of `str` from a `str`)

And if we take our example but instead slice `[:1]`?

```
>>> my_list[:1] = "ABCD"
>>> my_list
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '6', '7', '8', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

As we assigned to a slice that extends to index `1` (which includes index `0`, but not index `1`), you can see that we have lost `5` from our list, with the contents of `ABCD` being added to the list at the beginning.

And to demonstrate from the other direction:

```
>>> my_list[-1:] = "EFGH"
>>> my_list
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '6', '7', '8', '1', '2', '3', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Now we have inserted the sequence starting at index `-1` (or the last item in the sequence), and as such have lost `4` at the end of the `list`.